# Gauss Seidel moving mesh AMR hamilton Jacobi

Tags: matlab, pde, algorithms, numerical-analysis, nonlinear-equations

I was trying to implement a moving mesh algorithm using Gauss Seidel, so:

I have a pde like this (Hamilton - Jacobi eq)

$\begin{cases}\phi_t+H(\phi_x)=0 & [-1,1]\times [0,T]\\\phi(x,0)=\phi_0 & t=0\end{cases}$

and I do this each step:

```
a) Use a standard solver to approximate solution (one step more in time)
b) Do 5 Gauss Seidel iteration to adapt grid 
c) interpolate solution on the new grid
d) repeat until t=T
```

Now I have some problems with (b), maybe my weight function is not properly calculated:

equidistribution principle says:

$\omega(\phi_{j+1/2})(x_{j+1}-x_{j})-\omega(\phi_{j-1/2})(x_{j}-x_{j-1})=0$

so that my GS iteration is (using $n,n+1$ as time's index)

$\omega(\phi^n_{j+1/2})(x^n_{j+1}-x^{n+1}_{j})-\omega(\phi^n_{j-1/2})(x^{n+1}_{j}-x^{n+1}_{j-1})=0$

now if I want to use:

$\omega=\sqrt{1+\alpha|\phi_x|^2}$ , $\alpha>0$

and a central differencing for derivatives $\phi_x=\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\Delta^+_x\phi_j}{\Delta^+_xx_j}+\frac{\Delta^-_x\phi_j}{\Delta^-_xx_j}\right)$ , what's my linear system to solve?

A=\begin{bmatrix}1 & 0 &0 &0 & \dots & 0\\\dots \\0 &\omega_{j-1/2} & -\omega_{j+1/2}-\omega_{j-1/2} & \omega_{j+1/2} & \dots & 0 \\\dots\\0& 0 & \dots & 0 &\dots &1\end{bmatrix}
x=\begin{bmatrix}x^{n+1}_1 \\x^{n+1}_2 \\\dots \\x^{n+1}_j\\\dots \\x^{n+1}_M  \end{bmatrix}
b=\begin{bmatrix}-1 \\0 \\\dots \\0\\\dots \\1  \end{bmatrix}

Ax=b? I tried this with

$\omega_{j+1/2}=\omega\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\phi(x_{j+1})-\phi(x_{j})}{x_{j+1}-x_{j}}+\frac{\phi(x_{j})-\phi(x_{j-1})}{x_{j}-x_{j-1}}\right)\right)$

$\omega_{j-1/2}=\omega\left(\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\phi(x_{j})-\phi(x_{j-1})}{x_{j}-x_{j-1}}+\frac{\phi(x_{j-1})-\phi(x_{j-2})}{x_{j-1}-x_{j-2}}\right)\right)$

maybe this are wrong? my reference is [this article](http://www.math.pku.edu.cn/pzhang/articles/34.pdf) (2.2.1 par)